# Is it possible to render frames out of order?

Tags: rendering

I have a looped animation. On the first and last frames, there is nothing but a plain backdrop, and the object appears sometime during the middle of the animation. I'm rendering to an image sequence, then compiling to .gif with the help of [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

The problem is that the .gif thumbnail shows the first frame, which is the blank backdrop. This is especially problematic because I have multiple works in a series, and all of their thumbnails are the same blank backdrop. The animations are all 168 frames long. My workaround is to manually import frames 60-168 into ScreenToGif, then to import frames 1-59. However, this is fairly inconvenient. I've also tried shifting the keyframes to achieve the same effect but, again, it's a substantial amount of unnecessary work.

Is there a way to render frames out-of-order and effectively renumber or remap the frames? For example, I'd like to save frames 60-168 as `frame[0001-0108].png`, and frames 1-59 as `frame[0109-0168].png`.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no frame offset property. You would have to rename the renderings using python when finished. An automated way I can think of is copying the files into a new folder by specifing the 'split frame' and create the gif by using ffmpeg. Would this help?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this via scripting.  Here I modified an existing script that would do your remapping of frame# into file index#.  You would adjust `firstBreak` to 60 and `lastFrame` to 168.

````
import bpy

filepathFmt="//render/frame {0:04d}.png"

firstBreak=8
lastFrame=11

###
### for list of shape types, N loops, create a set of objects, render and save, and clean up:
###
fp=""
outFileIdx=1

### render from firstBreak to lastFrame:
for frameIdx in range(firstBreak, lastFrame+1, 1):
    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame=frameIdx)
    print("frame=" + str(frameIdx))
    # format filename string using different index
    fp = filepathFmt.format( outFileIdx )
    print(outFileIdx)
    print( fp )
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fp
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
    outFileIdx+=1

print("remap")

### render from frame 1 to firstBreak-1:
for frameIdx in range(1, firstBreak, 1):
    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame=frameIdx)
    print("frame=" + str(frameIdx))
        
    ### render and save:
    # format filename string using different index
    fp = filepathFmt.format( outFileIdx )
    print(outFileIdx)
    print( fp )
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fp
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
    outFileIdx+=1
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would also do it with scripting. This solution renames already rendered files. It reads most stuff from your Blender settings - but it also assumes those settings are correct and didn't change since you rendered the files. **It also assumes there's no additional files other than those rendered in the render directory!**

Running the script once will shift the frames by specified number (I've set it to 100) - you could also uncomment line 11 to shift by half of the animation, so it starts exactly in middle.

Running the script a second time will unshift the frames back.

**I just wrote this script so it's not thoroughly tested.**

```
import bpy, os

offset = 100  # that many frames will be moved from the end to the beginning
shifted = "shifted"  # base of filename after shifting

scene = bpy.context.scene
path, orig_base = os.path.split(scene.render.filepath)
start = scene.frame_start
end = scene.frame_end
anim_len = end - start + 1
# offset = int(anim_len/2)  # set offset to half of the animation

for i, filename in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(path))):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if base.startswith(shifted):
        # restore
        new_frame_num = start + (i-offset) % anim_len
        new_filename = f"{orig_base}{new_frame_num:04}{ext}"
    else:
        # shift
        new_frame_num = start + (i+offset) % anim_len
        new_filename = f"{shifted}{new_frame_num:04}{ext}"
    print(f"Renaming {filename} to {new_filename}")
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```

Comment: Don't worry, looks nice and should work fine.